# libSVMの交差検証をJavaでeclipseを使ってやる方法

Tags: java, eclipse

eclipseで次のことをしようと思って以下のコードを書きました。
・output.txtのlibSVM形式のデータを入力として、svm_trainを実行する。
・パラメータに-v 3を追加して交差検証を行う。
・libSVMからの出力をコンソールに表示する。

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class libSVM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "C:\\Users\\Name\\workspace\\libsvm-3.24\\windows\\svm-train.exe","-v 3",
                "output.txt");
        pb. redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println(pb.redirectInput());
        System.out.println(p.waitFor());
        System.out.println(p.exitValue());
            try (var reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    builder.append(line);
                    builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
                String result = builder.toString();
                System.out.println(result);
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

また、libsvm.jarをビルドパスに追加しました。
しかし、コンソールには以下のように表示されます。

```
PIPE
1
1
n-fold cross validation: n must >= 2
Usage: svm-train [options] training_set_file [model_file]
options:
-s svm_type : set type of SVM (default 0)
    0 -- C-SVC      (multi-class classification)
    1 -- nu-SVC     (multi-class classification)
    2 -- one-class SVM
    3 -- epsilon-SVR    (regression)
    4 -- nu-SVR     (regression)
-t kernel_type : set type of kernel function (default 2)
    0 -- linear: u'*v
    1 -- polynomial: (gamma*u'*v + coef0)^degree
    2 -- radial basis function: exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)
    3 -- sigmoid: tanh(gamma*u'*v + coef0)
    4 -- precomputed kernel (kernel values in training_set_file)
-d degree : set degree in kernel function (default 3)
-g gamma : set gamma in kernel function (default 1/num_features)
-r coef0 : set coef0 in kernel function (default 0)
-c cost : set the parameter C of C-SVC, epsilon-SVR, and nu-SVR (default 1)
-n nu : set the parameter nu of nu-SVC, one-class SVM, and nu-SVR (default 0.5)
-p epsilon : set the epsilon in loss function of epsilon-SVR (default 0.1)
-m cachesize : set cache memory size in MB (default 100)
-e epsilon : set tolerance of termination criterion (default 0.001)
-h shrinking : whether to use the shrinking heuristics, 0 or 1 (default 1)
-b probability_estimates : whether to train a SVC or SVR model for probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0)
-wi weight : set the parameter C of class i to weight*C, for C-SVC (default 1)
-v n: n-fold cross validation mode
-q : quiet mode (no outputs)
n-fold cross validation: n must >= 2
Usage: svm-train [options] training_set_file [model_file]
options:
-s svm_type : set type of SVM (default 0)
    0 -- C-SVC      (multi-class classification)
    1 -- nu-SVC     (multi-class classification)
    2 -- one-class SVM
    3 -- epsilon-SVR    (regression)
    4 -- nu-SVR     (regression)
-t kernel_type : set type of kernel function (default 2)
    0 -- linear: u'*v
    1 -- polynomial: (gamma*u'*v + coef0)^degree
    2 -- radial basis function: exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)
    3 -- sigmoid: tanh(gamma*u'*v + coef0)
    4 -- precomputed kernel (kernel values in training_set_file)
-d degree : set degree in kernel function (default 3)
-g gamma : set gamma in kernel function (default 1/num_features)
-r coef0 : set coef0 in kernel function (default 0)
-c cost : set the parameter C of C-SVC, epsilon-SVR, and nu-SVR (default 1)
-n nu : set the parameter nu of nu-SVC, one-class SVM, and nu-SVR (default 0.5)
-p epsilon : set the epsilon in loss function of epsilon-SVR (default 0.1)
-m cachesize : set cache memory size in MB (default 100)
-e epsilon : set tolerance of termination criterion (default 0.001)
-h shrinking : whether to use the shrinking heuristics, 0 or 1 (default 1)
-b probability_estimates : whether to train a SVC or SVR model for probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0)
-wi weight : set the parameter C of class i to weight*C, for C-SVC (default 1)
-v n: n-fold cross validation mode
-q : quiet mode (no outputs)
```

戻り値も1なのでどこかおかしいようです。
どのように直したらいいですか？

Comment: "-v 3" を"-v" "3"にしたら上手く行きました。自己解決しました